# How to use Mac OS X audio API functions?

Tags: c++, macos, api, audio

When reading about the Mac OS X audio API, they seem to list quite a few functions, but not (that I can find) how to use them.

For instance, they list a subclass, `IOAudioLevelControl`. Should I just create an object with this, and assume that it controls the audio level? And if so, what should I assume? That it has a constructor that sets the audio level, so I should declare them `IOAudioLevelControl levelControl(5);`?

I'm very confused here.

Edit: My goal is to make a program that detects the audio level of all the running programs(like Chrome when you play music from Youtube etc) and lower the level if it goes over a certain level, set by the user.

Answer (score 3):

IOKit is *way* too low level - it's the user-space proxy for device drivers on the system.  MacOSX provides several layers that sit about this.  Most likely, you can use these APIs directly without being root.

[Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) provides the next layer up in the stack.  [The diagram](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH3-SW1) on this page shows the architecture.

Setting CoreAudio are higher level APIs such as Audio Units and AVFoundation.  It is likely that are what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how will I use the Core Audio then? Just use the functions based on their name and hope it comes out okay, or is there a better explaining for every function?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to describe what you want to achieve?